# Stored procedure with JSON input to create a table definition

Tags: c#, sql, json, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am to create a stored procedure to create a table to capture form data, this is part of a bigger project to create a Form Generator.

I was wondering if anyone had created a stored procedure that took a stringified JSON object as input and created the the table based on this schema?

I'm still toying with this in my brain as to whether I should be doing this within the sproc (preferable) or writing dynamic sql within a C# Service.

Comment: Since stored procedure creation syntax and semantics varies wildly between sql versions your chance to have answers would be bigger if the sql version is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't approach this problem by passing the JSON string to a stored procedure.  However, if you wish to do it this way you could pass the JSON object directly to the stored procedure and then manipulate the string as below.  I have provided the code to manipulate the table name and create a table based upon the example JSON string '{TABLENAME:TABLENAME, Fields: {field1:varchar, field2: int }}'.  You would then have to modify this to include fields and datatypes based upon the string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateTableFromJSON
(
    @JSON       VARCHAR(100)
)

AS

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) 

SET @TableName = SUBSTRING(@json, CHARINDEX(':', @json)+1, CHARINDEX(',', @json) -CHARINDEX(':', @json)-1)


DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)

SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' +  @TableName + ' (ID INT)'

EXEC(@SQL)

GO

EXEC CreateTableFromJSON '{TABLENAME:TABLENAME, Fields: {field1:varchar, field2: int }}'
```